# Cypress Should fails test keeps running

Tags: cypress

I am writing a test to confirm page sizing is working properly and after I got the success I purposely configured the test to fail. The should fails, but the test just keeps running instead of failing out.

```
describe("Customers' Page size changes correctly", function () {
    it("Should change the page size properly.", () => {
        // SETTING UP THE INTERCEPT DETECTION THAT SAYS THAT THE PAGE HAS BEEN LOADED
        cy.intercept(
            "/api/v1/customers/?action=customers&pageSize=10&pageNumber=1&searchText=&filterByCustomerName=false&orderBy=CreatedOn&orderDirection=desc&partyDateStart=&partyDateEnd=&customerStatus=Active"
        ).as("rSearchRequest10");

        cy.getToken().then(() => {
            cy.visit("customers");
        });

        // Standard page size of 10
        cy.wait("@rSearchRequest10").then(() => {
            // Defaults to 10, should get 10 results.
            const listResults = cy
                .get("[data-testid=customersList]")
                .find("[data-testid=customerListItem]");
            assert.isNotEmpty(listResults);
            listResults.should("have.length", 11);
        });
    });
});
```

I get the message

> expected [ <div#eu.MuiBox-root.jss166>, 9 more... ] to have a length of 11 but got 10

Then the timer just keeps running. I have no further tests and feel the test should have failed at this point.

---

What does cy.getToken() look like? –

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getToken", () => { 
  cy.intercept('dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track', { 
    fixture: 'External/track-service-response.json' 
}); 
cy.request('GET', 'test/bridge'); });
```

---

The solution is below.  My final code looks like this.  The expect within the then properly throws the error and stops the execution of that test.

```
it("Should default to page size 10", () => {
    cy.intercept(
        "/api/v1/customers/?action=customers&pageSize=10&pageNumber=1&searchText=&filterByCustomerName=false&orderBy=CreatedOn&orderDirection=desc&partyDateStart=&partyDateEnd=&customerStatus=Active"
    ).as("rSearchRequest10");

    cy.getToken().then(() => {
        cy.visit("customers");
    });

    // Standard page size of 10
    cy.wait("@rSearchRequest10").then(() => {
        // Defaults to 10, should get 10 results.
        cy.get("[data-testid=customerListItem]").then((listing) => {
            expect(listing).to.have.lengthOf(10, "Should be exactly 10 results");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What does `cy.getToken()` look like?

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add("getToken", () => {
    cy.intercept('https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track', { fixture: 'External/track-service-response.json' });
    cy.request('GET', 'test/bridge');
});

Comment: You may have success by passing in the done function, `it("Should change the page size properly.", (done) => {....listResults.should("have.length", 11); done(); }`.

Comment: Does your solution work if you put the `assert` back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using "expect":

```
// Standard page size of 10
    cy.wait("@rSearchRequest10").then(() => {
        // Defaults to 10, should get 10 results.
        var searchResponse = cy.get("[data-testid=customerListItem]").then(listing => {
            expect(listing).to.have.lengthOf(11, "Your error message for failing");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain why? `expect` inside `.then()` does not retry.

Comment: the expect does throw the error and stop the test as I would anticipate.  My final version looks like this.

cy.wait("@rSearchRequest10").then(() => {
 // Defaults to 10, should get 10 results.
 cy.get("[data-testid=customerListItem]").then((listing) => {
  expect(listing).to.have.lengthOf(10, "Should be exactly 10 results");
 });
});

Answer (score 1):

Unsure why it continues to run but suspect part of your problem has to to with [async nature of cypress selectors](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Closures).

Instead of setting `const listResults` to a var you should chain off of the `cy.get` or `.find` with a new `.then()`

in this case it seems like you could do without the assert.isNotEmpty and just go straight to `.should()`

```
cy.get("[data-testid=customersList]")
  .find("[data-testid=customerListItem]")
  .should("have.length", 11);
```

Comment: fixed the extra `;` 
setting the result of a selector to a var and asserting on that is a bad idea though. It can definitely lead to flaky tests so its good to at least eliminate that problem even if it isn't the root of the ongoing test run.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  This var and assert were done in an effort to try other ways of asserting to see if I could get the test to fail other than doing a timeout.  The final version is as above, but at this time it still will not fail until the timeout hits.